# Access MainWindow variable from class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a WPF application to simulate traffic. I want the `Car`s to have a reaction delay of 1 second befor changing their acceleration, without stopping the whole application. To do so, I want to acces the `elapsed` variable from my `Car` class. The `elapsed` variable stores how much time has passed.

The code in `MainWindow`:

```
namespace TrafficTester
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //create the timer
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        timer.Interval = timerInterval;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        //...

        void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Enabled = false; //stop timer whilst updating, so updating won't be called again before it's finished
            update(); //
            timer.Enabled = true;
            elapsed += timerInterval;
        }
    }
}
```

The code in the `Car` class:

```
namespace TrafficTester
{
    public class Car
    {

    //...

        public void changeAccel(double val)
        {
            int time = MainWindow.elapsed;
            int stop = MainWindow.elapsed + reactDelay;
            while (time < stop)
            {
                time = MainWindow.elapsed;
            }
            accel = val;
        }
    }
}
```

`accel` is the current acceleration and `val` is the new acceleration. `MainWindow.elapsed` should call the `elapsed` variable from MainWindow, but it doesn't. How can I call it from the `Car` class?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Oops, I probably should've stated that a little more clearly. I can't acces the elapsed variable in the MainWindow from the Car class. I just edited the question as well.

Comment: How do you create new `Car` instance in `MainWindow`?

Comment: I've got another class, `TrafficController`, which has a for-loop that puts `Car`s in a `List` on startup.

Comment: You didn't show us how you declared that `elapsed` field, but `MainWindow.elapsed` will only work if it's a public static field. However, static fields are generally not recommended because of their global nature: they're easy to work with initially but tend to make code much harder to maintain in the long run. It's better to pass the elapsed time to your cars through a method call instead.

Answer (score 2):

I saw at least 2 problems:
- If you want to access the timer intance, it needs to be public.
- Then you can access it via an instance of your Mainwindow.

To get the elapsed time, like you probably want, you need to go from you ElapsedEventHandler and do the timing action there!

```
public  partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public MainWindow()
        {

    //create the timer
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent); // Where is it?
    myTimer.Interval = 5;
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    //...

    void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Enabled = false; //stop timer whilst updating, so updating won't be called again before it's finished
        //update(); //
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
     //   Timer.Elapsed += 5;
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public void changeAccel(double val)
    {
        var myWin = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        int time = myWin.myTimer.Elapsed; //<-- you cannot use it this way

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tweaked around a little with what you said and now it works :)